# How would i get the live feed from peek preview?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm making an app that I want to display the live feedback of another app, windows has the peek preview feature but I need a way to get this feed to display in my app yet I cant find anything on here or in the Windows API.

There are ways you can set it to a thumbnail and so on but I don't want that, I just want the video feed of the window either it be peek preview or something else that hardly uses the CPU [image]

Comment: Use DwmRegisterThumbnail. [Sample code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130513-00/?p=4393/). Converting to C# left as an exercise.

Comment: I will test this out in a few days :) Thanks